# Rails: Routing Error uninitialized constant RegistrationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to implement `devise` authentication using ajax and jquery. I generated devise controllers using:

`rails g devise:controllers users` It created all the necessary controller files required such as `sessions`, `registration`.

These are the controller files:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    respond_to :html, :json
end

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    respond_to :html, :json
end
```

**routes.rb** file looks like below:

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 'registrations'}
```

As soon as I fill the registration form and hit enter I get:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant RegistrationsController
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the namespace in your routes

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
                   sessions: 'users/sessions', 
                   registrations: 'users/registrations'}
```

Answer (score 2):

change routes.rb from

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 'registrations'}
```

to

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'users/sessions', registrations: 'users/registrations'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when working on a **Rails** 6 application.

I had my model named `application_registration.rb`

My views directory was `app/views/application_registrations`

And my routes was: `resources :application_registrations, only: [:create, :update, :new, :edit]`

But it was throwing an error:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationRegistrationsController Did you mean ApplicationController
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue arose from the naming of my controller.

I had named it `application_registrations.rb`

All I had to do was to rename it to `application_registrations_controller.rb`

That's all

**I hope this helps**